# Android:SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /103.24.4.60 (port 80) after 30000ms

Tags: android

I want to download image from Http url and save into sd card after that load and show into image view. I have tried Image-loader tutorial from android-hive used my http url for load the image but after run image can't load and show. App is not crash but getting error exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /103.24.4.60 (port 80) after 30000ms` in **ImageLoader** class

Here is my Log information

```
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /103.24.4.60 (port 80) after 30000ms
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.imgloader.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:73)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.imgloader.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:23)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.imgloader.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:134)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-30 02:32:15.820  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-30 02:32:15.821  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-30 02:32:15.821  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-30 02:32:15.821  18371-18389/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is ImageLoader class

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: how large is the image? It took 30secs to timeout, possible that the image is too large or you have slow internet speed.

Comment: Image size is 4568 by 6987

Comment: That's too large and the app probably will get an out of memory error. You can resize the image into a safer scale

Comment: You simply cannot make a connection to the server. Maybe a firewall issue?

Comment: You can increase your 30000 to 60000 or more if you want to download it

Comment: @NaviRamyle look at the stack trace, it fails much earlier at trying to establish a connection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1) Have you checked and tested your connection.

2) Better don't set any connection timeout,if you are setting chose maximum time, because it throws an error,if server didn't response within given time.

so you can use:

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
```

or you can use:

```
for (int retries = 0; retries < 3; retries++) {
    try {
        final HttpClient client = createHttpClientWithDefaultSocketFactory(null, null);
        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("GET Request on '" + get.getURI().toString() + "' resulted in " + statusCode);
        } else {                
            return response.getEntity();
        }
    } catch (final java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // connection timed out...let's try again                
   }
}
```

hope so it will helps you,
enjoy your code :)

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly , can we download mp3 using ImageLoader

Comment: If you don't set timeout, it will use a default one, for instance, 15000. So, 30000 is better.

Answer (score 18):

I also had this problem. In my case, I was trying to connect my Android app with node REST api which was running on port 3000. I also had this connection timeout problem. My OS is windows.

Folow these steps.

**1)-   Check whether the mobile and Computer are connected to same network**

**2)-Check the computer IP assigned by router using below comand on cmd**

```
ipconfig
```

The result will be like this

```
Windows IP Configuration

  Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ********
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ********
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : ********
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ********
                                   ***.***.8.1
```

Then check the used IP address. It must be **IPv4 Address** of the connected wifi network

**3)-Set the network as private/ Home network**

On windoes 10, you can do this by *select taskbar **wifi icon** ==> selecte the **properties** of connected network ==> Under Network profile set the network as **private***

**4)-Check the Firewall is disabled.**

If your firewall is enabled please turn off it until test finish and remember to turn on it again after finishing your task

Answer (score 7):

**This issue can occur due to FIREWALL, please check below steps to resolve it**

1. Check whether you can connect directly through URL, using any of
   browser instead of Android app.
2. If it fails, then it could be an
   issue with network connectivity not with android code.
3. One of reason behind Network connection failure is "FIREWALL" option, which
   might be blocking connection request.
4. In case of MAC machine, open "System Preferences==>Security & Privacy ==> Firewall ==> Turn Off Firewall". It will turn of FIREWALL on system.
5. In case of other OS, please turn off FIREWALL with respective settings.

Now you should be able to connect through code as well direct through browser, hence there won't be any "SocketTimeoutException" error. Good Luck.

Comment: Exactly. The firewall was the reason for rejecting the connection to my local server. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was resolved when my phone was connected to the local server wifi in which the webservices were hosted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really. Basically, while testing an API on Android Studio with a real phone, make sure you are on the same network.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an emulator in android studio, and have never accessed the network through it, then try launching the browser and accepting the agreement.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31142306)

Answer (score 0):

for window user

type ipconfig in your cmd
find out the ipv4 IP address, it is your post URL IP address
then find out the port number and disable your network firework

done

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes if your system from where you are trying to start Metro bundler is connected to VPN will cause such errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

My android phone had AnonyTun (vpn app) connected.
Disconnecting was the solution.